# How do I repeat vector elements by times in another vector elements in R?

Tags: r

I want to repeat each

```
repeat.it <- c(0, 3951982, 7635488, 10986941)
```

by times:

```
repeat.times<- c(2L, 3L, 4L, 2L)
```

and get the result:

```
0,0,3951982,3951982,3951982,7635488,7635488,7635488,7635488,10986941,10986941
```

code I tried:
`rep(repeat.it, each=repeat.times)` but this seems to give me wrong results. How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 3):

Almost there:

```
rep(repeat.it, times = repeat.times)
#  [1]        0        0  3951982  3951982  3951982  7635488  7635488
#  [8]  7635488  7635488 10986941 10986941
```

Comment: @MAPK, does it answer your question?

Answer (score 1):

This is an option

```
res <- mapply(rep, repeat.it, repeat.times)
res <- unlist(res)
```